# Why would "standardizedAddress" stop showing in responses from Google Address Validation

Tags: google-address-validation-api

I've been using Google's new Address Validation API for quite a few months.  This morning multiple customers have told me they're getting a response that "standardizedAddress" is not found.

I looked into it and I see that the API is responding, but somehow the USPS standardizedAddress is no longer in the JSON it returns.

It was always in the response until this morning, but now it's missing regardless of what address is submitted, and which customer is running it.

I made some code changes to check to see if it's there so it doesn't trigger an error, but I'm wondering why it's gone... and whether this is a temporary thing, or something that is permanent.  I'm paying hundreds of dollars each month for the API primarily to make sure my customers have accurate addresses, especially counties, but as far as I know, the USPS standardizedAddress is the only part of the API that can return the county, so this is a problem for me.

My code hasn't changed in months, the standardizedAddress is no longer in the response.

Comment: See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/294140306

Comment: Thank you for posting the IssueTracker.  It looks like they were made aware of the issue and although they took a few days, fixed it.  For what it's worth, it created a flood of calls from frustrated customers who couldn't lookup counties or accurately standardize their addresses this week.  It made me look for other vendors including Smarty and PostGrid who have similar APIs as a backup or replacement.